# Android parse XML from SDcard about special tags

Tags: android, android-xml, android-parser

i have a little problem by parsing an xml file, which is on the sdcard of my smartphone.

the xml-structure look like :

```
....
<nd ref="1364745028"/> 
<nd ref="1364745137"/> 
<nd ref="2121048622"/> 
<nd ref="2121048651"/> 
<tag v="forest" k="landuse"/> 
</way> 
-<way id="25089587"> 
<nd ref="273065498"/> 
<nd ref="273065777"/> 
<nd ref="1882290182"/> 
<nd ref="1882290194"/>
....
```

i want especially the value "forest". how can i get the value? 
my currently code look like:

```
....
try {
   File root = android.os.Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/xmls/xapi.xml");

NodeList tag = document.getElementsByTagName("tag");
for(int i = 0; i < tag.getLength(); i++) {
  Element element = (Element) tag.item(i);
  NodeList value = element.getElementsByTagName("k");
  Element line = (Element) value.item(0);
  parameter.setText(line.getTextContent());
}
}catch(SAXException e) {
....
}catch(IOException e) {
....
}
```

the app crushes, when i click a button, in which onlick-method is these try-catch block. anyone an ideo, how to fix it? thanks in advance.

**EDIT1**
the error-message

```
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3100)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3095)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    ... 11 more
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    at com.example.parsexml.MainActivity.ReadXMLFromSD(MainActivity.java:116)
02-20 17:54:42.495: E/AndroidRuntime(12627):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: post the stacktrace of your exception.

Comment: Which line is MainActivity.java:116?